# How can I execute my code when someone open my Google Form?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want that execute this code everytime that someone open my Google Form, cause I want that the responses will be available in a specific time, but when I open the form out of the hour 17-21, the form is available to response. But if I press the button "execute" in google script the code works well.

So, how can I execute this code?

Thanks

```
function myFunction() {

  stop_Accepting_Responses();

  function stop_Accepting_Responses() {
    var thisForm;
    thisForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();//Get the Form

    var d = new Date();
    var h = d.getHours();


     if (h>=17 && h<21){ 
        thisForm.setAcceptingResponses(true);
     }else{
        thisForm.setAcceptingResponses(false);
     }
   }

}
```

Comment: I suspect that you'll have to  create your own form with a web app for something like that.

Comment: Apps Script never executes in the "response" mode of Google Forms--only the "edit Form content" mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in on the Sheets side instead of Forms using time triggers. Open a new Sheets spreadsheet and go to the script editor. Use code like the following.

```
// get the form's id

function Stop_Accepting_Responses() {
   var formUrl = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/12.../edit";
   FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl).setAcceptingResponses(false);
}

function Start_Accepting_Responses() {
   var formUrl = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/12.../edit";
   FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl).setAcceptingResponses(true);
}
```

**Edit > Current project's triggers**, and create a new time-based trigger for the hour you want to run your start and stop functions.